# JAVA 17 Junit test cases failing with java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException

Tags: java, junit, mockito, java-17, java-16

java version:17 mockito version:5.3.0

As I am upgrading to java 17, junit test cases are failing with reason:

> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @38cccef

Please suggest some solution as I CANNOT use solutions:

1. —add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
   or
2. --illegal-access=permit (removed in java 17)

I am expecting to solve this problem by adding any new dependency in pom.xml or different version of mockito. with minimal code change.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

add this to pom:

```
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0</version>
<configuration>
<argLine>--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: In your question you said you can’t use `—add-opens`, now your “solution” is exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions in the mockito release notes under '5.0.0' [here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/releases/tag/v5.0.0). Essentially, switch the mockmaker implementation.

That, or downgrade back to JDK11.